# Display list of third party site requests

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I get a list of all third party site requests (cross-site requests) made by a webpage I'm on? Do I log all the http request headers then strip everything off other than the GET URLs or is there an easier way to do this? I can't seem to find anything on Chrome's API page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to use the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` method to intercept all outbound web requests.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log("calling " + details.url);
});
```

You can even configure the listener to only trigger on xmlhttprequest calls, see method references below.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#apiReference

Comment: Thank you, it worked! It seems that I can't leave the second and third args for `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` empty. I solved it by passing in an empty object/array.